# C# Bytes from Textbox to Value

Tags: c#, decode

I have a Winform with one input textbox, one button and one output textbox.

Right now my code works the following way:

I click the button and the preset bytes in "string value" will be decoded to readable text and output to the output textbox using "string decoding1".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = decoding1(new byte[]
            {
                104,
                107,
                102,
                102,
                110,
                103,
                116
            });
    }

    public string decoding1(byte[] byte_0)
    {
        textBox2.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoding2(byte_0));
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoding2(byte_0));
    }
```

But now I want to be able to input these bytes "104, 107,..." into the input textbox so the program decodes and outputs them, otherwise I would have to manually input different bytes into the source code each time and this would be a waste of time for me.

How could I approach that, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single line TextBox and separate your "bytes" with comma or use a multi-line TextBox and have one "byte" per line. Any separator you can think is OK, probably.

Then, you convert those byte number to actual bytes using the `byte.Parse()` method. The code could go something like:

```
string[] splittedBytes = txtInputBytes.Text.Split(',');
byte[] bytes = splittedBytes.Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

The `Split()` method will "break" the input at each separator, a comma in this example. The next line converts those parts of input into actual bytes, using the `Select` Linq method to apply the `byte.Parse()` to each input element. You can also use a `for` statement or any other way. Then decode the bytes to a actual string and display it.

Comment: I hope it could be of some help :)

Comment: Also note that if you use input values outside the byte range [0-255] you get an error. And if you use a byte value greater than 127 and the bytes don't conform to UTF-8 you might get and error or gibberish output.